# Using SQL query in QGIS Database Manager?

Tags: qgis, sql

I have below query which I am supposed to import into QGIS by amending certain aspects, to find out exactly what it does. But when I try to run it on the corresponding PostGIS layer, DB Manager warns me that there is not such "geom" attribute. I don't know what to do then. Is it a syntax issue?

```
UPDATE c_risque.ppr_inondation_surf 
SET    geom = st_multi(st_simplify(st_multi(st_collectionextract(st_forcecollection(st_makevalid(st_snaptogrid(geom, 1))),3)),0))
WHERE  not st_equals(geom, st_multi(st_simplify(st_multi(st_collectionextract(st_forcecollection(st_makevalid(st_snaptogrid(geom, 1))),3)),0)));
```

Comment: Does `c_risque.ppr_inondation_surf` actually *have* a column named `geom`? Also, consider this: you test each rows geometry for `<complicated_geometric_processing>`, and if it's not equal, do and set `complicated_geometric_processing>`; while that seems to make sense, it would be faster to just set everything to `<complicated_geometric_processing>` (except you'd have a functional index on `<complicated_geometric_processing>`...which you likely don't want).

Answer (score -1):

Try the following :

1) ensure u really have a geometry column in your **ppr_inondation_surf** table (...)

2) reference the geometry column using '**geometry**' instead of geom

**PS** : i think u can't launch **update** queries in QGIS Database Manager ("virtual layers") ...

Comment: am i wrong ? ...